# I keep getting a KeyError when I use a variable as [key] in [dictionary].pop([key])

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I don't get KeyError when I use a constant (whose value is the same as the variable) for [key].

For example:

```
self._answer= input("Which appointment would you like to delete?")
self._useless= self._book.pop(self._answer)
```

Gives a key error when self._answer= 1001, however:

`self._useless= self._book.pop(1001)`

works as desired. Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Edit: As @user2357112 suggested below, the following piece of code worked: `def deleteAppointment(self):
        self._answer= int(input("Which appointment would you like to delete?"))
        del self._book[self._answer]`

**However**, after redoing  the entire project I no longer ran into the problem above (i.e. using [dictionary].pop([key]) no longer produced a KeyError). **Therefore, if you are getting this error there is likely a bug in your code.**

Comment: Is the key integer 1001 or string "1001"?

Comment: @Rogalski Yes I'm trying to remove a key from the dictionary self._book.

Comment: @timrau It's an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` on Python 3 returns a string, and `'1001' != 1001`. If your key is the int `1001`, you will need to convert the input to an int:

```
self._answer= int(input("Which appointment would you like to delete?"))
```

As an aside, the name `self._useless` indicates that you might not care about the result of the `pop` operation. If you just want to remove the entry from the dict, you can use `del`:

```
del self._book[self._answer]
```

or you could ignore the return value of `pop` and not assign it to anything:

```
self._book.pop(self._answer)
```

Comment: Thanks you user2357112, your second suggestion using del worked. As a side note, your first suggestion didn't work for me: when I tried it there were no errors, however 1001 was still in the dictionary.

Comment: @AshutoshMishra: Sounds like you've got more bugs somewhere.